# how set json values to calendar event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to give json values to calender event,my json values comes from database.but bellow code is not working

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("sd");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


            type:"GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calender_view_get_json.json',

            events: [

                ],                    
        });

    });

</script>
```

I dont know what to do for set the json data's can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: can you pls share the error you are getting

Comment: `events: '/Controller/Method'`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("sd");
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: calender_view_get_json.json,
    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}',
    events: [],
  });
});
```